# Memory usage of simple SDL2 program grows linearly

Tags: sdl2, linux

I am a newbie in SDL2 and I was testing an example code of [Lazy Foo SDL tutorial](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/03_event_driven_programming/index.php) just out of curiosity. The program renders an image named x.bmp living in the same folder as the program. Here’s the example program testsdl2.cxx:

```
/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2022)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

//Starts up SDL and creates window
bool init();

//Loads media
bool loadMedia();

//Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

//The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;

//The image we will load and show on the screen
SDL_Surface* gXOut = NULL;

bool init()
{
  //Initialization flag
  bool success = true;

  //Initialize SDL
  if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
  {
    printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    success = false;
  }
  else
  {
    //Create window
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    if( gWindow == NULL )
    {
      printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
      success = false;
    }
    else
    {
      //Get window surface
      gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow );
    }
  }

  return success;
}

bool loadMedia()
{
  //Loading success flag
  bool success = true;

  //Load splash image
  gXOut = SDL_LoadBMP( "x.bmp" );
  if( gXOut == NULL )
  {
    printf( "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", "03_event_driven_programming/x.bmp", SDL_GetError() );
    success = false;
  }

  return success;
}

void close()
{
  //Deallocate surface
  SDL_FreeSurface( gXOut );
  gXOut = NULL;

  //Destroy window
  SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
  gWindow = NULL;

  //Quit SDL subsystems
  SDL_Quit();
}

int main()
{
  //Start up SDL and create window
  if( !init() )
  {
    printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
  }
  else
  {
    //Load media
    if( !loadMedia() )
    {
      printf( "Failed to load media!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
      //Main loop flag
      bool quit = false;

      //Event handler
      SDL_Event e;

      //While application is running
      while( !quit )
      {
        //Handle events on queue
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
        {
          //User requests quit
          if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
          {
            quit = true;
          }
        }

        //Apply the image
        SDL_BlitSurface( gXOut, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );

        //Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );
      }
    }
  }

  //Free resources and close SDL
  close();

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled this with:
`clang++ -std=c++20 -g -fsanitize=address -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 testsdl2.cxx -o vimbin`

Running the binary shows some memory leaks. Heard that address sanitizer sometimes produces false leaks reports so I decided to profile the memory usage of the binary. Here I am attaching the graph of memory usage:

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I installed SDL2 by this:

`sudo apt install libsdl2-dev`

So what’s wrong with the program? Or is my SDL2 setup wrong? Or is it something wrong with the library itself? How can I get rid of the leaks? Just tell me if any additional information is needed.

Comment: @Zibelas I see no leak related report in that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh looks like all this happened just because I compiled this in address sanitizer mode.  The program is keeping track of every block of memory ever allocated or freed for as long as the program is running so of course its total memory usage is increasing over time. Because it’s got more short-lived temporary allocations to track forever the longer the application runs. This also explains why it starts up using such an absurd amount of memory for a program which is doing so little.

So I just removed `-fsanitize=address` from the compilation flags and it returned to normal flat memory usage.